# AES code in Openssl

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to modify AES-256-CBC code in openssl package, let me say I want to put some printing messages.

my problem is that I can't locate AES exact code, I've found some aes.c files under 
openssl/crypto 
but even if I deleted those files and re-compile the package it still works.

so the core code maybe else where, any help locating and modifying aes-256-cbc code ?

Comment: Can you explain what you did exactly? How did you modify the OpenSSL code? (provide a diff) How did you compile it and build the package? How did you install it? Which application do you use to consume the modified OpenSSL library? Did you restart the application after replacing the library?

Comment: modifying: adding some lines to aes-cbc.c code.
re-compiling using
./config
make
make install ... in main openssl folder.
testing: using /usr/local/openssl commands to encrypt some data file.

Comment: I understood that much. Can you show us those modifications? It's hard to say where things went wrong, because there are so many steps involved in the process.

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to get a better idea. What's the output of `ldd /usr/local/openssl`?

Comment: linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff301fe000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f87208e8000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8720520000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8720b00000)

but I have no idea what does that mean.

Comment: I means that the executable isn't linked against the system `libssl.so` (compare with `ldd /usr/bin/openssl`). In that case you'll need to provide a [diff](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format) between the original OpenSSL code and your modified version. Something along the lines of `diff -u aes-cbc.c.orig aes-cbc.c`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already removed openssl of the system using `apt-get remove openssl`

Comment: `libssl.so` resides in the `libssl` package though. The `openssl` package just contains some tools around those libraries.

Comment: so what should I do to edit or modify openssl algorithms ? let's say I want to add something to aes code.

Comment: See my [previous comment](/questions/562460/aes-code-in-openssl?noredirect=1#comment773294_562460).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I've found my answer, in OpenSSL source package there are two codes for AES. Therefore, there are two ways to edit it:

1. In `/cyrpto/aes/asm` there is an assembly code written in `Perl`, so if you want to edit it you will have to go through assembly code.
2. In `/crypto/aes` there is code written in `C`, and it is easier to modify and work with.

> Note: in the 2nd method, when you configure the package, you MUST use the option `no-asm`. 
>   meaning you don't to compile the assembly code and therefore forcing the package to use the code that written in `C`.